# Drawing a image to a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've already searched and found nothing about this topic, so I'll ask here.

I'm starting to develop very basic games, and I want to load a picture into my background. I'm using a eBook on Python to help me do this and, according to it, the following code is right:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

Width = 1000
Height = (Width/12)*9

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Monster Rush")
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=Width, height=Height, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.canvas_height = 500
        self.canvas_width = 500
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="anipedra.gif")
        w = self.bg.width()
        h = self.bg.height()
        for x in range(0, 5):
            for y in range(0, 5):
                self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
        self.sprites = []
        self.running = True

    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.running == True:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprite.move()
                    self.tk.update_idletasks()
        self.tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)

class Enemy(Game):
    def __init__(self):
        self.e = Game()
        self.e.mainloop()

class Player(Game):
    def __init__(self):
        self.e = Game()
        self.e.mainloop()

Troll = Enemy()
Grunt = Enemy()
Minion = Enemy()
Player = Player()
```

But every time I run this:

1. If it's a .gif, the IDLE normally shows this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Nuno\Desktop\Python\Projectos\Monster Rush\Monster Rush (T.D.).py", line 47, in <module>
  Troll = Enemy()
    File "C:\Users\Nuno\Desktop\Python\Projectos\Monster Rush\Monster Rush (T.D.).py", line 39, in __init__
  self.e = Game()
    File "C:\Users\Nuno\Desktop\Python\Projectos\Monster Rush\Monster Rush (T.D.).py", line 20, in __init__
  self.bg = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
    File "C:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3393, in __init__
  Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
    File "C:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3349, in __init__
  self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
  _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.gif"
```

2. If it is the .gif in the above code (or any other format):

   **The file stops responding and crashes.**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: the TCL image class has difficulty with some image types, look into `PIL` (python image library) and it's replacement `pillow` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.1.1

Comment: Are you certain your file is actually a gif file, or did you just rename a file from .png to .gif?

Comment: Why are you creating four root windows? Are the enemies and players really supposed to each be in a separate window?

Answer (score 2):

The error in your stack trace is saying that the file isn't really a GIF file. Are you certain it is actually a gif file, or could it be some other file that someone renamed to have .gif as a suffix?

You also have several critical design flaws.

1. In a well designed tkinter app you must always have exactly one root window.  You're creating four (or eight...) -- one for each player and enemy object.
2. You have classes that both inherit from `Game` and create a `Game` instance itself. This makes absolutely no sense. Either inherit from Game or create an instance, but don't do both. Though, since `Game` creates a root window, it makes no sense to create more than one `Game` object.
3. You aren't using the event loop properly. You aren't ever letting tkinter process certain events. You have your own infinite loop in which you call `update_idletasks()`, but that only handles screen refreshes and other "idle" events. It won't handle key presses or mouse clicks. You call `update` but it outside of the infinite loop so it never gets called.

   4. As a general rule of thumb you shouldn't be calling `sleep` in a GUI. It does exactly what it says: it puts your application to sleep. While it's sleeping it won't refresh the screen and it won't process mouse or keyboard events. The application is truly dead.

While I don't know exactly what your intentions are, you can probably rewrite your own custom `mainloop` to leverage the real event loop by doing something like this:

```
def mainloop(self): 
    if self.running == True: 
        for sprite in self.sprites: 
            sprite.move() 
        self.tkafter(30, self.mainloop)
```

You need to set `30` to represent how fast you want the display to update. The value is in milliseconds, so 30 represents 30fps. Also, you need to call the `mainloop` function of the root window exactly once so that it can process events.

Comment: I'm just a kid who is trying to improve in python and other languages, but your explanation is to complex for me. Some parts  I understand, but badly, because i don't have a large programming knowlegde so, if you could "kid" your explanation I would apreciate.

Comment: BTW, I'm trying to do a Tower Defense game

Comment: P.S.: The file I wanted to open with Tkinter is truly a .gif (Double checked).

Comment: @naapperas: I recommend you start off by just trying to draw one little ball on a screen and make it move. Once you get that down, adding multiple players and game logic will be easier. You're trying to do too much at one while at the same time trying to learn the language.

Comment: I was just trying to do what Jason Briggs did in his "Python for kids" book.

Comment: By the way, if you know how to make a tile map in python please let me know or send the link of the tut.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ! Some image software's can and do at times change the extension endings to image files. They can capitalize the extensions on demand. Such as .gif to .GIF or jpeg to JPEG etc. You wont realize this until you upload the files onto a website, then you will see the capitalized extensions. Googles infamous Picaso Download did this to my computer and i had to do a re system install to fix it. Not related but Windows alters the jpeg format also in secrecy in some older XP versions. Have someone test your code on another machine.